# Websphere 8.5 java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: ssl, db2, websphere-8

let me put across how frustrated I am with WebSphere right now. Yes the Theatre is WebSphere Application Server 8.5 and the protagonist is SSL. I have followed the IBM guide for enabling SSL encryption to a database source found here : http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21667093. Which I have had success with before on different nodes. However I just cannot fathom why this is just not playing ball. When I test the data source  it throws this error. I have looked around and it appears no one has reported the same issue online in the same set of circumstances. The only deviation I should point out that I am applying self signed certificate at the node level and not the cell level.

My database cfg has SSL enabled and I am connecting across on the designated port. This portion checks out ok.

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at com.ibm.jsse2.j.a(j.java:42)
at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.a(qc.java:116)
at com.ibm.jsse2.ab.a(ab.java:413)
at com.ibm.jsse2.ab.a(ab.java:255)
at com.ibm.jsse2.bb.a(bb.java:42)
at com.ibm.jsse2.bb.a(bb.java:614)
at com.ibm.jsse2.ab.s(ab.java:373)
at com.ibm.jsse2.ab.a(ab.java:140)
at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.a(qc.java:701)
at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.h(qc.java:453)
at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.a(qc.java:547)
at com.ibm.jsse2.h.write(h.java:8)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.fb.b(fb.java:1685)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.fb.a(fb.java:1633)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.a.C(a.java:390)
... 107 more
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at com.ibm.jsse2.util.h.a(h.java:3)
at com.ibm.jsse2.util.h.b(h.java:123)
at com.ibm.jsse2.util.g.a(g.java:13)
at com.ibm.jsse2.yc.a(yc.java:74)
at com.ibm.jsse2.yc.a(yc.java:163)
at com.ibm.jsse2.yc.checkServerTrusted(yc.java:160)
at com.ibm.ws.ssl.core.WSX509TrustManager.checkServerTrusted(WSX509TrustManager.java:372)
at com.ibm.jsse2.wc.checkServerTrusted(wc.java:58)
at com.ibm.jsse2.bb.a(bb.java:157)
... 117 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.buildCertPath(PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.java:642)
at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.engineBuild(PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.java:356)
at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:256)
at com.ibm.jsse2.util.h.a(h.java:37)
... 125 more
java.sql.SQLException: [jcc][t4][2030][11211][3.61.65] A communication error occurred during operations on the connection's underlying socket, socket input stream, 
est() - flush (-1).  Message: com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target. ERRORCODE=-4499,
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ed.a(ed.java:319)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.a.a(a.java:461)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.a.a(a.java:456)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.a.C(a.java:397)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.a.r(a.java:354)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.o.i(o.java:220)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.b(b.java:1111)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.c(b.java:696)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.b(b.java:682)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.a(b.java:365)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.<init>(b.java:305)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2PooledConnection.<init>(DB2PooledConnection.java:84)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2ConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnectionX(DB2ConnectionPoolDataSource.java:411)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2ConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(DB2ConnectionPoolDataSource.java:220)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.DSConfigHelper$1.run(DSConfigHelper.java:1266)
at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5387)
at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5603)
at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.ServerFunction$6.run(ServerFunction.java:567)
at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.DSConfigHelper.getPooledConnection(DSConfigHelper.java:1281)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.DSConfigHelper.getPooledConnection(DSConfigHelper.java:1189)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.DSConfigurationHelper.getConnectionFromDSOrPooledDS(DSConfigurationHelper.java:2071)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.DSConfigurationHelper.getConnectionFromDSOrPooledDS(DSConfigurationHelper.java:1947)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.DSConfigurationHelper.testConnectionForGUI(DSConfigurationHelper.java:2814)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
at com.ibm.ws.management.DataSourceConfigHelperMBean.testConnectionToDataSource2(DataSourceConfigHelperMBean.java:556)
at com.ibm.ws.management.DataSourceConfigHelperMBean.testConnection(DataSourceConfigHelperMBean.java:484)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:88)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:292)
at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1261)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:303)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:88)
at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1255)
at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:1093)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:832)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:814)
at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1335)
at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1228)
at com.ibm.ws.management.commands.AdminServiceCommands$InvokeCmd.execute(AdminServiceCommands.java:251)
at com.ibm.ws.console.core.mbean.MBeanHelper.invoke(MBeanHelper.java:241)
at com.ibm.ws.console.core.mbean.ResourceMBeanHelper.testNode(ResourceMBeanHelper.java:860)
at com.ibm.ws.console.core.mbean.ResourceMBeanHelper.testConnection(ResourceMBeanHelper.java:292)
at com.ibm.ws.console.resources.database.jdbc.DataSourceDetailAction.testConnection(DataSourceDetailAction.java:713)
at com.ibm.ws.console.resources.database.jdbc.DataSourceCollectionAction.execute(DataSourceCollectionAction.java:339)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:79)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:964)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1104)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1385)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:194)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.setUpCommandAssistance(WSCUrlFilter.java:964)
at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.continueStoringTaskState(WSCUrlFilter.java:511)
at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.doFilter(WSCUrlFilter.java:332)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:964)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1104)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:914)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1865)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at com.ibm.jsse2.j.a(j.java:42)
at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.a(qc.java:116)
at com.ibm.jsse2.ab.a(ab.java:413)
at com.ibm.jsse2.ab.a(ab.java:255)
at com.ibm.jsse2.bb.a(bb.java:42)
at com.ibm.jsse2.bb.a(bb.java:614)
at com.ibm.jsse2.ab.s(ab.java:373)
at com.ibm.jsse2.ab.a(ab.java:140)
at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.a(qc.java:701)
at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.h(qc.java:453)
at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.a(qc.java:547)
at com.ibm.jsse2.h.write(h.java:8)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.fb.b(fb.java:1685)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.fb.a(fb.java:1633)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.a.C(a.java:390)
... 107 more
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at com.ibm.jsse2.util.h.a(h.java:3)
at com.ibm.jsse2.util.h.b(h.java:123)
at com.ibm.jsse2.util.g.a(g.java:13)
at com.ibm.jsse2.yc.a(yc.java:74)
at com.ibm.jsse2.yc.a(yc.java:163)
at com.ibm.jsse2.yc.checkServerTrusted(yc.java:160)
at com.ibm.ws.ssl.core.WSX509TrustManager.checkServerTrusted(WSX509TrustManager.java:372)
at com.ibm.jsse2.wc.checkServerTrusted(wc.java:58)
at com.ibm.jsse2.bb.a(bb.java:157)
... 117 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.buildCertPath(PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.java:642)
at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.engineBuild(PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.java:356)
at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:256)
at com.ibm.jsse2.util.h.a(h.java:37)
... 125 more
```

Comment: Can you please confirm that you have added or retrieved the certificate from DB2 in the cellDefaultTrustStore?

Comment: @Don Draper, I got the same issue, and wonder how did you get around?

Comment: I am also facing same problem, how you resolved this?